# Merge the opportunity line item and opportunity product

Tags: discussion, tag-merge

After reading the [Relation Between Opportunity Products and Opportunity Line Items](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/30994/3357), I think that the following tags should be synonyms.

[opportunity-lineitem](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opportunity-lineitem) [opportunity-product](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opportunity-product)

Does anyone agree or disagree?

Comment: I'll buy that. Which one should be the master, though?

Comment: @metadaddy I would argue that opportunity-lineitem should be the master, because the opportunity-product is not used in the salesforce api documentation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK - [opportunity-product](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opportunity-product) is now a synonym for [opportunity-lineitem](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opportunity-lineitem), with the latter as master.

Tags merged!

Answer (score 5):

I agree. I would have proposed them as synonyms myself, but that requires at least 5 points in the tag.